# SQL Query for Parent Child and grand Relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 3 different table for `control_ledger` which is parent, `group_ledger` is first child and `ledger`
is grand child.

This is the sql in wrote for the output which is given bellow

SQL:

```
SELECT c.control_ledger_name, b.group_ledger_name, a.ledger_name
FROM acc_setup_ledger as a 
JOIN acc_setup_group_ledger as b
ON a.group_ledger_id=b.id
JOIN acc_setup_control_ledger as c
ON a.control_ledger_id=c.id
GROUP BY a.ledger_name
```

Output:

[image]

now i want to show this in table data.

expected Output:

```
Control Ledger 1
  Group Ledger 1
       Ledger 1
  Group Ledger 2
       Ledger 2
       Ledger 4

Control Ledger 2
  Group Ledger 1
       Ledger 5
       Ledger 7
  Group Ledger 2
       Ledger 9

Control Ledger 3
  Group Ledger 3
       Ledger 3
```

Comment: *This is the sql in wrote for the output which is given bellow* This query is wrong, it contradicts ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY and may give incorrect/non-deterministic output.

Comment: @Akina yes i know this might not help but i am trying to solve this problem and need some help

Comment: If so then provide a sample: CREATE TABLE scripts, INSERT INTO scripts with sample data, desired output for this data. Specify precise MySQL version also.

Comment: @Akina I provided a link in previous comment

Comment: Do not use such links, only permanent links may be used. I have seen - too wide, too many excess tables and data. Remove excess tables/columns/FKs, decrease rows amount (3-5-10 rows per table, not more) then create online fiddle (or post the scripts into the question text). And show desired output **for this data strictly**. And specify **precise** MySQL version also.

Comment: @Akina Server version: 10.4.17-MariaDB

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232969/discussion-between-julker-nien-akib-and-akina).